# Dynamic Visible Row Count In JList

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jlist, rowcount

I have JList that grows in size along with the `JFrame`. I have the following code:

```
defaultListModel = new DefaultListModel<SData>();
for (String string: listOfStrings) {
    defaultListModel.addElement(string);
}
jList = new JList<String>(defaultListModel);
jList.setCellRenderer(jListCellRenderer);
jList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
        //codes to go
    }
});
jList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
jList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL_WRAP);
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);
```

If I set some value for setVisibleRowCount method, the row number becomes fixed and If I don't set value, default value of 8 comes to play. I want to have this value dynamically changing.

Comment: what should control the visibleRowCount? Whatever it is, listen to that property and update the visibleRowCount accordingly.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `Size` of `JList` will have to control `setVisibleRowCount()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found that `jList.setVisibleRowCount(0)` makes it self adjustable, when resizing JList.

Comment: +1 A negative value works, too. See also [`getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize%28%29).

Comment: @trashgod, inside the `setVisibleRowCount` method, they were checking for `max(0,paramRowCount)`, so sending negative value or zero doesn't matter. It will take zero only. :)

Answer (score 1):

Echoing @kleopatras's comment, it's not clear what controls `setVisibleRowCount()`. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5760093/230513) grows the enclosing `Window` as rows are added, up to a predefined limit, then the scrollbar takes over. It might give you some ideas, or you can use it as the basis of your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) as @Andrew suggests.

Addendum: If the size of `JList` will control the count, I'd start with half of the model's `size()`. Then add one visible row for every *n* added to the model, in a fixed ratio that is pinned to a predefined limit. To maintain a reliable count, you'll have to implement your own `ListModel` or override the mutators in [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html).

Comment: `Size` of `JList` will have to control `setVisibleRowCount()`