# Display only 4 records and add a scroll bar to JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have added a JList, and made it to only display 4 records at a time. If there are more than 4 records the user should be able to scroll and view other records. But in my case, i get to see all 8-10 records that i added. The code is not showing the first 4 records and the scroll bar. Can someone tell me what i'm missing ?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class FrameTest {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JFrame frame;
    private FrameTest ft;
    private JList list;

    public FrameTest() {
        initComponents();
        ft = this;
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        list = new JList();
        list.setVisibleRowCount(4);
        list.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
            String[] values = new String[] {"adf", "gr", "rg", "g", "tg", "gt", "tg", "tg", "t", "gt", "gt"};
            public int getSize() {
                return values.length;
            }
            public Object getElementAt(int index) {
                return values[index];
            }
        });
        list.setSelectedIndex(1);
        panel.add(list, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

note: Above is a simplified version of my code.

Comment: You are missing reading some documentation on JList: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html`setVisibleRowCount()` should help

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5760093/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `JList` to `JScrollPane` and adding the scroll pane to you frame.

```
    panel.add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

The `visibleRowCount` is used by `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` to determine the number of rows that should be displayed in a scroll pane

Answer (score 1):

`setVisibleRowCount()` changes the size *preferences* of the JList, but the actual size is determined by which Layout Manager is laying out the JList. Some layouts take notice of the preferred sizes, others don't.

The documentation says:

> For a VERTICAL layout orientation, this sets or gets the preferred
>   number of rows to display without requiring scrolling. For the
>   HORIZONTAL_WRAP or VERTICAL_WRAP layout orientations, it defines how
>   the cells wrap.

More details in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

Use `JScrollPane` to achieve the scroll bar.

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
    panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Details in the tutorial here: [**Using JScrollPane**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)