# Expanding JTable Inside JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, preferredsize

I have the following layout that looks like this:

[image]

But I would like the table at the top to be minimized to just the headers, then grow vertically as clients are added. How do I go about doing this? Here is the code currently......

```
JFrame frame;
JTable clientTable;
DefaultTableModel clientTableModel;
JTextArea messageArea;

...

String[] tableColumnNames = ...
Object[][] data = ...

Toolkit toolkit =  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();
Dimension dim = toolkit.getScreenSize();

frame = new JFrame("Server");

clientTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0);
clientTableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(tableColumnNames);

clientTable = new JTable(data, tableColumnNames);
clientTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(dim.width-30, 82));
clientTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
clientTable.setModel(clientTableModel);

messageArea = new JTextArea(8, 40);
messageArea.setEditable(false);
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) messageArea.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);      

frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(clientTable), "North");
frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), "Center");
frame.pack();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Could not seem to find something to solve your problem. Maybe one of the Swing's experts will come by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you invoke [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--), the enclosing `Window` will be "sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents." Override `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` and return a suitable multiple of the row height. In the fragment below, `N` is the number of rows after which you want the scrollbar to appear.

```
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel) {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        int h = Math.min(N, table.getRowCount());
        return new Dimension(dim.width - 30, table.getRowHeight() * h);
    }
};
```

When you add a new row, invoke `pack()`, and the enclosing `Window` will adopt the new size. This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5760093/230513) illustrates the effect for a `JList`.