# how to increase JFrame size according to number of JPanel(table) rows in swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, window, jpanel

I have swing application which does following:

```
public void init() {
    jFrame = new JFrame();
...
    jFrame.add(sortingDataInputComponent.asComponent()); 
...
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.toFront();
}
```

there sortingDataInputComponent is JPanel with

```
jPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

inside of which there is another JPanel with

```
jPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,numberOfColumns));
```

where

```
private final int numberOfColumns = 3;
```

and inner jpanel grows at button press:

```
    jPanel.add(rowElement.getLabel(), insertionIndex);      
    jPanel.add(rowElement.getField(), insertionIndex + 1);
    jPanel.add(rowElement.getDeleteButton(), insertionIndex + 2);

    rowElements.add(rowElement);

    jPanel.revalidate();
    jPanel.repaint();
```

but the main windows does not grow with JPanel.
It has the same initial size. How to make JFrame grow with the growth of inner JPanels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the [`Scrollable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable) interface in the component to which you add rows and override [`getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33789834/230513) for `JTable` and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5760093/230513) for `JList`.  Invoking `pack()` on the enclosing `Window` will cause it to be "sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents."