# How can I change the size of a JPanel to fit a dynamically generated JBList?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jpanel, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to create a popup plugin for IntelliJ.  The popup contains a JPanel (parentPanel), which contains a JList (I use JBList which is just a sublcass for Intellij) and JTextField.  The contents of the list are built dynamically, depending on the contents of the JTextField when the user presses TAB.

This is what I am currently trying.  The result is that a new JList is constructed with the proper elements, but the JPanel stays the exact same size, so most of the JList is obstructed.  How can I expand the panel (and the whole popup) so that the entire list is visible?

Am I doing something wrong with JPanel, or is the size constrained by the popup itself?

parentPanel receives GridLayout from this line

```
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
```

Here is the code which modifies the JList.

```
DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel) parentPanel.getFileList().getModel();
listModel.removeAllElements();
VirtualFile[] children = currentPathFile.getChildren();

for(int i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
   listModel.addElement(children[i].getPath());
}
parentPanel.remove(1); // The list is the panel's second child
parentPanel.add(new JBList(listModel));
parentPanel.revalidate();
parentPanel.repaint();
```

Even if I give the GridLayout 10 rows, the JList only occupies one row.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If `parentPanel` is a `JPanel`, its default layout is `FlowLayout`, which retains the initial preferred size, typically defined by the preferred size of the original content. Try changing it to `GridLayout`, which will allow the list to grow and shrink as the enclosing panel is resized.

> That doesn't work either. `GridLayout` code has been added.

Because [`JBList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/12.0/com/intellij/ui/components/JBList.java) extends [`JList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html), you may be able to use `setVisibleRowCount()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5760093/230513).

Comment: That doesn't work either.  Gridlayout code has been added.

Comment: I'm not sure where your approach fails. Can post a [mcve]? I've cited an example above for reference.