# JList updating with Object returning arraylist

Tags: java, swing, client, jlist

I have a Client_manager named CM that return an arrayList.

```
public class Client_Manager {
private static Client_Manager self = null;
private ArrayList<Client_Thread> clientList;
public Client_Manager() {
    self = this;
    this.clientList = new ArrayList<>();
}



public static Client_Manager getInstance()
{
    if(self == null)
        self = new Client_Manager();

    return self;
}

public void addClientThread(Client_Thread client)
{
    this.clientList.add(client);
}

public Client getClientAt(int index)
{
    return this.clientList.get(index).getOwner();
}

public void removeClient(int index)
{
    this.clientList.remove(index);
}

public ArrayList<Client> getClientList() {
    ArrayList<Client> ar = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int count1 = 0; count1 < clientList.size(); count1++)
    {
        ar.add(clientList.get(count1).getOwner());
    }

    return ar;
}
}
```

and Jlist named 'showClient'. What i am trying to do is get the arraylist from CM.(CM.getClientList) to show up in the jlist showClient. Furthurmore, i want it update the changes every time CM get new clients. How should i begin?  first time assignment with swing.

Need someone to point me to the right direction either documents or an examples. ...

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Sounds like you're after some kind of [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `ClientManager` contain a [`ListModel<Client>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) that is updated with each added `Client`. Any listening `JList` having that model will update itself in response.  Complete examples may be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5760093/230513). The exact details depend on context, but the `ListModel<Client>` *must* be updated on the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). If receiving clients causes unpredictable latency, use a [worker thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Comment: i was told that it is not suppose to have any graphical component in clientmanager class.

Comment: Please edit your question to an [mcve] that reflects this requirement. `ClientManager` needn't contain any view component; it just needs to update the view's model.